# How to include a directory in a nuget package

Tags: teamcity, publishing, nuget-package, octopus-deploy, post-build-event

I have a post build event in project which copies a folder that is not included in project to a shared directory in project.

```
xcopy /Y /E "$(TargetDir)\Views\Shared\CommonScripts" "$(ProjectDir)\Views\Shared\CommonScripts"
```

Now problem is it works fine If I publish it locally. but If I try to do it using teamcity which is creating a nuget package on build and then publish using octopus. That folder is not included. I try to add it in a nuspec file as follows:-

```
<files>
<file src="$CommonScriptsSource$" target="$CommonScriptsDestination$" />
</files>
```

and then defining the prameters in teamcity build parameters but this is also not working. Also please guide how can I make this folder part of a nuget package. or How can I replicate post build event in nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

By design NuGet excludes some directories (i.e. those starting with a dot).

Try to create a nuget package from commandline on your machine using the [nuget pack](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference) command and open it with [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/): it contains the empty directory?

If so you can simply modify the TeamCity build to package your project with that commandline (using a [Command Line build step](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Command+Line)).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here you can do the following..
[How to add a folder to a nuspec file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551235/how-to-add-a-folder-to-a-nuspec-file/24551639#24551639)

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\Release\**\*.*" target="content" /> 
</files>
```